# Verify my construction of an analytic isomorphism from $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, mobius-transformation

One of the problems assigned to me for homework was to construct an analytic isomorphism from $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1)$. Here is my attempt at a solution, but I am worried that it is not analytic at a certain point. To be more specific, I don't think my solution is analytic when $z = \sqrt{2}i$.

> First, consider the following Analytic Isomorphism:
>           $$f(z) = -iz$$
>           It is clear that $f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H, \mathbb H_R)$. Next, consider the following isomorphism:
>           $$g(z) = z^2$$
>           It is clear that $g \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H_R, \mathbb C\backslash(-\infty, 0])$. Therefore, $g \circ f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H, \mathbb C\backslash(-\infty, 0])$:
>           $$(g \circ f)(z) = -z^2$$
>           Next, consider the following isomorphism:
>           $$h(z) = 1-z$$
>           It is clear that $h \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb C\backslash(-\infty, 0], \mathbb C\backslash[1,\infty))$. Therefore, $h \circ g \circ f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H, \mathbb C\backslash[1,\infty))$:
>           $$(h \circ g \circ f)(z) = 1+z^2$$
>           Finally, consider the following isomorphism:
>           $$j(z) = \frac{z}{|z|+1}$$
>           It is clear that $j \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb C\backslash[1,\infty), \mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1))$. Therefore, $j \circ h \circ g \circ f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H, \mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1))$:
>           $$\frac{1+z^2}{|1+z^2|+1} \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb H, \mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1))$$

Comment: "Analytic isomorphism" is strange terminology. Do you mean "biholomorphic map"? Also, what is $\mathbb H$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term biholomorphic map, but I believe that they are indeed the same thing.

Comment: Your map $j(z)$ is not analytic.

Comment: At $z=0$? That's what I was suspecting.

Comment: @zhw. Can you construct a function? I've tried and still can't find one.

Comment: I've given some hints below.

Comment: I think you were given some hints, because as it is, it is complicated (see @zhw answer) and not of your level if you don't see $\frac{z}{|z|+1}$ isn't analytic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: $f(z) =(z-1)/(z+1)$ maps the right half plane to $\mathbb D$ in a nice way.  The map $f(\sqrt {z})$ then maps $\mathbb H$ to the upper half of $\mathbb D.$ Square that map to yield a map onto $\mathbb D \setminus [0,1).$ Now compose with a biholomorphic self map of $\mathbb D$ that sends $\mathbb D \setminus [0,1)$ to $\mathbb D \setminus [1/2,1).$

Comment: Thanks you so much! I was able to construct one before you wrote these hints, but hopefully someone else will find them useful.

Comment: @Birdman2246 Not convinced you found one (and I don't think there are many solutions). Can you write it ?

Comment: I went the opposite direction. I used the function $-(z+1)/(z-1)$ to map $\mathbb D \setminus [1/2,1)$ to $\mathbb H_R \setminus [3, \infty)$. From there, I used the function $1/z$ to map $\mathbb H_R \setminus [3, \infty)$ to $\mathbb H_R \setminus (0, 1/3]$. I used $3z$ to map $\mathbb H_R \setminus (0, 1/3]$ to $\mathbb H_R \setminus (0, 1]$. I then used $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ to map $\mathbb H_R \setminus (0, 1]$ to $\mathbb H_R$. Finally, I used $iz$ to map $\mathbb H_R$ to $\mathbb H$. I think it is the same work, just I went the opposite direction.

Comment: $\mathbb H_R$ is the right half of the complex plane. In other words, it's $\{z:\text{Re}(z) > 0\}$.